# Plot functions in x,y Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Want to plot a function in xy coordinates with TikZ

Code so far

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$]
%Below the red parabola is defined

%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=250, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))};
\label{$sin((x))$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=250, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$cos(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=250, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$sin(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=250, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$cos(x)$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do i replace the x coordinate to align with 0 at x? 
And how to setup the scale for each axis? 
And i guess my sin(x) function is wrong are there special commands for functions?

edit: Now the scaling is bad. And have to set up the y axis correct and the labels?
[image]

Comment: `domain=0:10,` instead of `domain=-10:10,` or `axis lines=middle`? In any case, please provide a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The trigonometric functions in `pgf` assume degrees. Convert with `deg(x)`, or `x*180/pi`,  or add `trig format=rad` to the `axis` options. (Also, in the legend entry use `$\sin(x)$`, note the backslash before `sin`.)

Comment: The document is too large to do that.

Answer (score 3):

With `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=1cm, y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis x line shift=1.2,  
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
x label style={anchor=north},
y label style={anchor=east},
xmin=-0.5,xmax=9.8,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
xtick={0,...,9},
clip=false,
domain=0:9.1, 
smooth
            ]
\addplot[teal]              {sin(\x r)}     node[right]{$\sin x$};
\addplot[teal,dashed]       {sin(2*\x r)}   node[right]{$\sin (2x)$};
\addplot[magenta]           {cos(\x r)}     node[right]{$\cos x$};
\addplot[magenta,dashed]    {cos(2*\x r)}   node[right]{$\cos (2x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way with plain TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth,domain=0:9.2]
\draw[->] (-.5,-1.5)--(10.8,-1.5) node[below=1mm]{$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-1.6)--(0,1.5) node[left]{$y$}; 
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} 
\draw (\i,-1.5)--(\i,-1.6) node[below]{$\i$};
\foreach \j in {-1,0,1} 
\draw (0,\j)--(-.1,\j) node[left]{$\j$};

\draw[teal,dashed] plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)}) 
node[right]{$\sin (2x)$};
\draw[magenta,dashed] plot (\x,{cos(2*\x r)}) 
node[right]{$\cos (2x)$}; 
\draw[teal,thick] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) 
node[right]{$\sin x$};
\draw[magenta,thick] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)}) 
node[right]{$\cos x$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```